# What will I have to write in my program so that it would only accept commas in their proper location (i.e. cannot input 10,00.0 , 100,0.2334, etc)?

Tags: c++, c++11, parsing, c++14, string-parsing

I am taking a summer course in computer science, and I get assigned two projects a week, so bear with me if I'm getting some terminology wrong.

This week, I was able to get the first one done, but not the second one. In the second assignment, we were required to rewrite the ReadDouble function so that it's more user-friendly; user-friendly as in allowing the user to input commas along with numbers. Additionally,

1. we were required to allow the first character to be a number, plus or minus sign, or a decimal point.
2. All other characters can be a number, comma, or decimal point (if there already wasn't one).
3. As mentioned, commas must be written in properly (we can't allow the user to input 10,00.244, 343,2.334, or some nonsensical number like that).
4. No commas should be allowed after the decimal point.
5. Only one decimal point should be allowed in the number.

So far, I was able to able to meet 1), 2), and 5). 3) and 4)? Not so much.

The underlying issue is that I don't know what classes, objects, and whatnot I should be using to make the program read the string input and determine if the commas were inserted properly. I have an idea that I would need to use something similar to the "input.length()" code, set it as a variable that can be compared in an if statement to ensure that the amount of digits until the next comma can be used is met.

I also tried writing a for loop that would check after the decimal place for commas or any other invalid character, but I didn't know what to write down as its initialization. How would I get the for loop to start looking from the decimal after it's aware that one decimal exists?

Another major issue I am encountering is that when I input something like 1.2, it is displayed as 12, meaning that "atof(convert.cstr())" has stripped the decimal from the return value. However, when I enter it as just .2, it comes out as 0.2.

I will provide the code of what I have written so far along with the code of what a friend has suggested to me.

My code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

// Main Menu Error Prototype
double ReadDouble(string prompt);

double ReadDouble(string prompt)
{
    string input;
    string convert;
    bool isValid = true;

    do {
        // Reset the flag to valid input
        isValid = true;

        // Read input from user
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> input;

        // Validate user input
        // Check the first character is a number, + or -
        int decimal = 0;
        if (input[0] != '+' && input[0] != '-' && input[0] != '.' && isdigit(input[0]) == 0) {
            cout << "Error! Input was not an integer.\n";
            isValid = false;
        }
        else {
            if (input[0] == '.') {
                decimal++;
                //cout << "." << endl;
            }
            convert = input.substr(0, 1);
        }

        // check that the remaining characters are numeric
        long len = input.length();
        for (long index = 1; index < len && isValid == true && decimal <= 1; index++) {
            if (input[index] == ',') {
                ;  // do nothing if character is a ','
            }
            else if (input[index] == '.') {
                decimal++; // do nothing if character is a '.'
                if (decimal > 1) {
                    cout << "Error! You can have only one decimal point.\n";
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
            else if (isdigit(input[index]) == 0) {
                cout << "Error! Input was not an integer.\n";
                isValid = false;
            }
            
            else {
                convert += input.substr(index, 1);
            }
            
        }


        // Start looking where the decimal starts 

        /*
        long decimal=input.find('.');
        for (decimal; decimal < len && isValid==true; decimal++) {
            if (input[decimal] =='.') {
                ; // do nothing if character is a '.'
            }

        }
        */
        //cout << "\nDecimal value is " << decimal << endl; -- Test Code
    } while (isValid == false);

    
    double returnvalue = atof(convert.c_str());
    
    return returnvalue;
}

int main()
{
    double x = ReadDouble("Enter a value: ");
    cout << "Value entered was " << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My friend's incomplete code:

```
ReadDouble(){
     isValid = true

     do{
            get user input and set it to a variable called input
            set output variable to a variable called output
            bool hasDecimal = false;
            int digitsUntilNextComma = 3

            for(i = 0; i < input length; i++){
                    if(input[i] == ','){
                             if((i < 3 && i > 0) || digitsUntilNextComma == 0){
                                     digitsUntilNextComma = 3;
                                     output += input[i];
                             }else{ //if it gets to here the comma was in a bad place like ,123 or 12,12,123
                                        isValid = false; 
                                        i = input length  //breaks out of for loop
                              }
                    } else if(input[i] == '.'){
                             if(i < 3 || digitsUntilNextComma == 0){
                                     if(hasDecimal){ //if this is true then the input had 2 decimals 
                                               isValid = false; 
                                               i = input length  //breaks out of for loop
                                      }else{
                                              hasDecimal = true;
                                              digitsUntilNextComma = 3;
                                              output += input[i];
                                       }
                             }else{ //if it gets to here, a previous comma was in a bad place like 12,34.56
                                      isValid = false; 
                                      i = input length  //breaks out of for loop
                              }
                    }else{
                            output += input[i];
                            digitsUntilNextComma--;
                    }
            }
          
     }while(isValid == false)
}
```

I hope what I provided wasn't too vague or messy. Again, I had little exposure to programming in the past, so forgive me if I mess some terminology up.

Comment: Maybe you're not thinking outside the box for this.  What is the maximum length of the data to the left of the decimal point?  Whatever it is, there are only a finite number of positions commas can appear.  For 1,2, and 3 digit numbers, no commas.  For a 4 digit number, the comma can only appear in one place, and it has to be after the first number.  For a 5 digit number, the comma can only appear after the second digit.  For 6 digits, after the third number, for 7 digits, only after the first and fourth digit, etc.

Comment: Then build a lookup table with this information.  Then it's just a matter of figuring out how many digits, and if there is a single comma in the number, whether the comma positions match what is in the lookup table for that digit count.  That's how many non-programmers would have approached the problem.  Check the number of digits, and then go to a table that shows what positions the commas should be in (if any), and then check the number to see if the commas are at those positions.  See, you don't need to be a programmer to figure out an alternative way to do this.

Comment: As to your question as to "what will I have to write in my program", that now becomes open-ended.  Someone could write a 5 or 10 line routine using STL algorithms that solves the problem.  So would that be considered as a solution?  I doubt if anyone would try to take what you wrote, attempt to do a few changes here or there, and get it to work properly, rather than just rewriting the whole thing in a more coherent fashion.

Comment: Also, what do you return from `ReadDouble` if the number is not valid?  You still go ahead and call `atof` on an invalid number.   Instead, you should throw some sort of exception.

Comment: Can you use `<regex>` to solve most of the validation in one go? Then just replace the commas and convert to double: https://ideone.com/TalpKD

Comment: You provided so much background that it's hard to see where your question is buried. You might want to review [ask].

Comment: Are "1,000000.0" and "1000,000.0" allowed?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this.  Which solution you should use probably depends a bit on what material is being covered in the class.  State machines, regular expressions, intro to the C++ standard library, just the `std::string` class, `<algorithms>`, data-driven algorithms, structured programming, ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for a FSM.

```
Start on + to IN0
Start on - to IN0
Start on Digit to IN1
Start on Decimal to D_prime
IN0 on Decimal to D_prime
IN0 on Digit to IN1
IN1 on Digit to IN2
IN1 on Decimal to D
IN1 on Comma to N0
IN2 on Digit to N3
IN2 on Comma to N0
IN2 on Decimal to D
```

IN# is "initial numbers, seen #".

```
D_prime on Digit to D
D on Digit to D

N0 on Digit to N1
N1 on Digit to N2
N2 on Digit to N3
N3 on Comma to N0
N3 on Decimal to D
```

Valid End states are N3, IN1, IN2, IN3 and D.

Any unexpected character is an input error.

For State, keep an accumulator, a sign, and a decimal count with initial state 0, positive, 0.

On Start(-) set sign to negative.

Whenever you see a digit, multiply accumulator by 10 and add it.

In D or D_prime state, also increase decimal count by 1.  D_prime exists to eliminate `.` as a valid number.

Result is (sign is negative?-1:1)*accumulator/10 to the power of decimal count.

To test this, write a program that generates valid numbers, another that generates gibberish, and another that randomly adds, subtracts, shuffles and splices characters from valid number(s).